# Why is my keyboard and mouse giving extra events when I try to upload stuff to YouTube?

Tags: keyboard, youtube

I am writing normally now. However, I am writing the below paragraphs when condition happens.

I delliberately leave in the typos so yoou can alll see what I amm faacing.

Bbasically I  trried to uplooad stuffs to youtube. Howeever, I noticed that everytime I did that sometthingg weird happeens.

My i7 computers become slow. It feels hheavy. Thhen I can't easily drag annd drrop stuffs because windows like adding extra click. The moouse is doing fine on another computer.

Even the keyboard is not functioning properly. I can type well, like right now I am typing well. However, when the computer is slow, some buttons I press end up getting pressed twice. Hence the typo above.

> [image]

First of all, it's weird that uploading anything to youtube can make computers less  responsive.  Whaat's eveen morree  weird iss mouses aand kkeeyboarrds add extra clicks ddurinng that.

Why?

I caann understtandd delayed response. But why the rrepeated reesponses?